# Query to find the column names of a table using BIgquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on project_name='Alpha' and dataset_name = 'Beta' and this dataset contains numerous tables. I want to get table details i.e, columns of a particular table i.e, table_name = 'Gamma'

Answer (score 0):

**To retrieve meta data information. you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA**.

Try with below query..

```
SELECT column_name FROM `project_name.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
WHERE table_name = <'Table Name'>;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your solution, You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

1. First, try with below:

`SELECT * FROM Alpha.Beta.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Gamma' ;`

2. Then you can select the details you want, only for the column name you can use below;

`SELECT column_name FROM Alpha.Beta.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Gamma' ORDER BY ordinal_position asc ;`

Please do let me know if it doesn't work out but flag it as an answer if it works.

EDIT: if it didn't work, can you please try putting `Alpha.Beta.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` between escape character

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the error

AND   can you please try putting Alpha.Beta.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS between escape character

Comment: documentation from Google on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS -  [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view)